# Spherical Collision

Tags: physics, game-mechanics

I have a made spherical collision system which creates a major problem, the balls gets stuck to each other on high speed and sometime with low speed collisions. I researched a lot but I couldn't found a single useful information.

Here's the logic code.

```
DetectCol(ball1, ball2)
{
    float x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2;
    center(ball1, x1, y1, z1);
    center(ball2, x2, y2, z2);
    float colr = ball1.rad+ball2.rad;
    float dist = (((x2-x1)*(x2-x1))+((y2-y1)*(y2-y1))+((z2-z1)*(z2-z1)));
    if(dist <= (colr*colr)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

The balls gets stuck together for few milliseconds.

```
updater
{

loop (i) for all balls
{
        getposition(i, tx1, ty1, tz1);
        loop (j) for all balls
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                getposition(j, tx2, ty2, tz2);
                delx = tx2-tx1;
                dely = ty2-ty1;
                if(DetectCol(i, j))
                {
                    angle = atan2(dely, delx);
                    nx1 = (firstBall.speed.x * (firstBall.mass – secondBall.mass) + (2 * secondBall.mass * secondBall.speed.x)) / (firstBall.mass + secondBall.mass);
                    ny1 = (firstBall.speed.y * (firstBall.mass – secondBall.mass) + (2 * secondBall.mass * secondBall.speed.y)) / (firstBall.mass + secondBall.mass);
                    nx2 = (secondBall.speed.x * (secondBall.mass – firstBall.mass) + (2 * firstBall.mass * firstBall.speed.x)) / (firstBall.mass + secondBall.mass);
                    ny2 = (secondBall.speed.y * (secondBall.mass – firstBall.mass) + (2 * firstBall.mass * firstBall.speed.y)) / (firstBall.mass + secondBall.mass);


                    newx1=nx1*cos(angle) - ny1*sin(angle);
                    newy1=ny1*cos(angle) + nx1*sin(angle);

                    newx2=nx2*cos(angle) - ny2*sin(angle);
                    newy2=ny2*cos(angle) + nx2*sin(angle);


                    firstBall.speed.x = newx1;
                    firstBall.speed.y = newy1;
                    secondBall.speed.x = newx2;
                    secondBall.speed.y = newy2;

                }
            }
        }

        velx = firstBall.speed.x/700.0;
        vely = firstBall.speed.y/700.0;
        velz = firstBall.speed.z/700.0;

        getposition(i, px, py, pz);
        updateposition(i, (px+velx), (py+vely), (pz+velz));
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: How is your collision detection relate to the fact that your balls get stuck together? Your method is constant and should not influence the balls. You should probably explain _how_ is your collision detection used, i.e. what is being done upon collision.

Comment: Oh sorry, updating in a minute or so.

Comment: Edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent of your code is unclear; adding comments would help us know what you're trying to do, and making sure that we don't have to scroll horizontally would really help.

The first thing I notice, though, is that you check your system AND your update it at the same time, which could result in the behaviour you have:

For balls A and B, if you inspect a collision between ball A and B, and there is a collision, you change the behaviour/state of A *immediately* without changing the behaviour/state of B, that is, you make A bounce off B, then you inspect a collision between B and A, there is no longer any collision (because you've just moved A in the same loop execution) so you don't change it's behaviour/state. They will still collide the next frame because B is keeping on going on its trajectory and it's going to keep pushing A away in an unexpected manner.

Maybe what you could do is two passes:

1. Check everything that collide and store the pairs into a list. You should avoid checking A with B, then B with A, as the result will be the same.
2. Parse the list you build in the previous pass and resolve the collisions by modifying the position/velocity of each ball of the collision.

Now if A and B collide, and B and C collide, and A and C collide, you have a more complex collision. What do you do?

Collision detection and physics simulation are quite complex subjects in their own. You can do some in simple ways in your implementation, you'll have to leave some more complex situation out for the sake of simplicity (for instance, don't manage the A and B and C intersection as a single collision, but 3 separate ones).

Or you could try and find and integrate a collision/physics engine that is readily available and integrate it to your software for increased realism.

Comment: Yes you are exactly correct, but how to "check everything that collide, then resolve the collisions (by modifying the behaviour/state of all the objects implied)"